# Netty: writeindex about "discard" Netty example

Tags: netty

This is a example in netty source package, I print the writeindex, 
I test one client, I want to know

```
public class DiscardClientHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
...
@Override
public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
    // Send the initial messages.
    generateTraffic(e);
}
@Override
public void channelInterestChanged(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
    // Keep sending messages whenever the current socket buffer has room.
    generateTraffic(e);
}

private void generateTraffic(ChannelStateEvent e) {
    // Keep generating traffic until the channel is unwritable.
    // A channel becomes unwritable when its internal buffer is full.
    // If you keep writing messages ignoring this property,
    // you will end up with an OutOfMemoryError.
    Channel channel = e.getChannel();
    while (channel.isWritable()) {
        ChannelBuffer m = nextMessage();
        if (m == null) {
            break;
        }
        channel.write(m);
    }
}
```

above is clint code...

```
public class DiscardServerHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    // Discard received data silently by doing nothing.
ChannelBuffer cb = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
    transferredBytes += cb.readableBytes();

    System.out.println("-=-=- " + transferredBytes + "-=-" + cb.writerIndex() + "-=- " + e.getMessage().toString());
    }
-=-=- 679039232-=-65536-=- BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=65536, cap=65536)
-=-=- 679072768-=-33536-=- BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=33536, cap=33536)
-=-=- 679105792-=-33024-=- BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=33024, cap=33024)
...
-=-=- 679298816-=-256-=- BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=256, cap=256)
-=-=- 679299072-=-256-=- BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=256, cap=256)
-=-=- 679299328-=-256-=- BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=256, cap=256)
...
-=-=- 679600640-=-65536-=- BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=65536, cap=65536)
-=-=- 679634176-=-33536-=- BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=33536, cap=33536)
-=-=- 679640576-=-6400-=- BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=6400, cap=6400)
....
```

I test one client, I want to know:

1. why the writeIndex sometimes 256, sometimes 65536?
2. why the biggest is 65536?

private ChannelBuffer nextMessage() { return ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(content);//content size is 256 } 
I want the one client use the same channel buffer, an writeindex increase sequence? am I right?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much data the read-operation was able to "read". So it can be different all the time. 65536 is 64k which is most likely the RECV_BUF size of your application, so it is the "max".

Comment: private ChannelBuffer nextMessage() {
        return ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(content);//content size is 256
    }

Comment: I want the one client use the same channel, an writeindex increase sequence? am I right?

Comment: I want the one client use the same channel buffer, an writeindex increase sequence? am I right?